# Create Button In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, menu

I am trying to create a button that pops up a menu in the center of my canvas.  I originally created a button in the HTML file that did this, but when my sprite updated every second it would put the canvas over the menu. So now I am trying to create it in the Javascript file.

Right now I have something like this:

```
function menuButton(ctx, func) {
    var button = document.createElement("menu");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "menu";
    button.onclick = func;
    ctx.appendChild(button);
}

window.onload = function () {
    createButton(canvas, function () {
        highlight(this.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
    });
}
```

But I am not getting anything to display on the screen for the button.  The goal is to get the button to always display, and then when clicked it will load a screen that has other buttons (ex. settings, stats, etc).

Answer (score 3):

`menu` is not a valid HTML element, so you can't create it.

```
function menuButton(ctx, func) {
    var button     = document.createElement("button");
    button.type    = "button";
    button.value   = "menu";
    button.onclick = func;
    ctx.appendChild(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any child nodes of a `canvas` element will only be rendered if the browser does not implement `canvas` (fallback content).

You'll need to create the button using the canvas drawing APIs instead. There are some great examples of how to do this on the [MDN Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial).

Hope that helps, cheers!